# Euler-Lagrange and Conservation of the Hamiltonian giving two different Equations of Motion

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, approximations

Consider the following Lagrangian:
$$L=mR\left[\frac{1}{2}R\left(\dot{\theta}^2+\omega^{2}\sin^{2}\theta\right)+g\cos\theta\right],$$
with an associated Hamiltonian
$$H=mR\left[\frac{1}{2}R\left(\dot{\theta}^2-\omega^{2}\sin^{2}\theta\right)-g\cos \theta\right].$$

If I take the Euler-Lagrange Equation, along with the small angle approximation $$\sin\theta=\theta,\,\cos\theta=1,$$ I end up with the second order ODE:
$$\ddot{\theta}=\left(\omega^2-\frac{g}{R}\right)\theta.$$
However, the conservation of the Hamiltonian (i.e., treating it as a constant),
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{\theta}}\dot{\theta}-L=H,$$
yields an entirely different differential equation with different solutions to the one generated by using the standard Euler-Lagrange equation:
$$\frac{H}{m}=\frac{1}{2}R\omega^2\theta^2-\frac{1}{2}R\dot{\theta}^2+g.$$
This leads to an entirely different result. Why is this happening?

Comment: The discrepancy (v2) seems caused by an inconsistent truncation of the small angle approximation.

Comment: Minor semantic comment (v2): OP's function $H(\theta, \dot{ \theta})$ is strictly speaking the energy function, not the Hamiltonian (although they have the same value).

Comment: @Qmechanic Can you explain what you mean "H is strictly speaking the total energy, not the Hamiltonian"? Given OP's starting point of a time-independent Lagrangian $L(\theta, \dot \theta)$, OP seems to just be turning the usual crank of: $H = pv-L$ where $p=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot \theta}$ and $v=\dot \theta$. And the resulting expression is conserved and equal to what OP denotes as $H$, the usual Hamiltonian.

Comment: @Qmechanic Do you mean the Hamiltonian should be expressed in terms of $p$ and $\theta$?

Comment: Your Hamiltonian is not correct ?

Comment: @Eli No, it is correct, as far as I can see. Why do you think it is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

Take your last equation, for the conservation of energy, except without making the small angle approximation in the cosine term.,
$$\frac{H}{m}=\frac{1}{2}R\omega^{2}\theta^{2}-\frac{1}{2}R\dot{\theta}^2+g\cos\theta.$$
Differentiating this gives
$$\frac{\dot{H}}{m}=0=R\omega^{2}\theta\dot\theta-R\dot{\theta}\ddot{\theta}-g(\sin\theta)\dot{\theta}.$$
If you *now* apply the small angle approximation to the sine term at the end, the equation reduces to
$$0=R\dot{\theta}\left(\omega^{2}\theta-\ddot{\theta}-\frac{g}{R}\theta\right),$$
which is clearly equivalent to what you got from the Euler-Lagrange equation.

There is a moral to this, which is that sometimes it is not sufficient to approximate $\cos\theta\approx1$, even when $\theta\ll 1$.  If you had used the next-order approximation $\cos\theta\approx1-\frac{1}{2}\theta^{2}$, the problem would have never arisen. The key point is that the potential $mgR\cos\theta$ only effects physical phenomena through its derivative. [In this case, the derivative is the torque $N=-\partial(mgR\cos\theta)/\partial\theta$, in the same way that a force is the linear derivative $F=-\partial V/\partial x$ of a potential.] So neglecting all $\theta$-dependence of $mgR\cos\theta$ is equivalent to dropping it from the theory entirely, since the derivative of a constant is zero.

Answer (score 0):

> Consider the following Lagrangian:
> $$L=mR\left[\frac{1}{2}R\left(\dot{\theta}^2+\omega^{2}\sin^{2}\theta\right)+g\cos\theta\right],$$
> with an associated Hamiltonian
> $$H=mR\left[\frac{1}{2}R\left(\dot{\theta}^2-\omega^{2}\sin^{2}\theta\right)-g\cos \theta\right].$$

OK, this looks fine.

> This leads to an entirely different result. Why is this happening?

The Lagrangian and Hamiltonian equations of motion lead to the same result, so the problem must be your approximation.

---

The Lagrangian equation of motion is:
$$
mR^2\ddot\theta = mR^2\omega^2\sin\cos - mRg\sin \tag{1}
$$

---

The Hamiltonian equations of motion are:
$$
-mR^2\omega^2\sin\cos +mRg\sin = -\dot p\;,
$$
where $p = mR^2\dot\theta$
and
$$
\frac{p}{mR^2} = \dot\theta\;,
$$
which can be combined to give:
$$
mR^2\ddot\theta = mR^2\omega^2\sin\cos - mRg\sin\;,\tag{2}
$$
which is the same as Eq. (1).

Answer (score 0):

this is the non linearized Hamiltonian

$$H=\frac 12\,m{R}^{2}{\dot\varphi }^{2}-\frac 12\,m{R}^{2}{\omega}^{2} \left( \sin
 \left( \varphi  \right)  \right) ^{2}-m\,R\,g\cos \left( \varphi 
 \right) 
$$
the equation of motion (  Hamiltonian is the energy )

$$\frac {dH}{dt}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial \dot\varphi}\,\ddot\varphi+
\frac{\partial H}{\partial \varphi}\,\dot\varphi=0\tag 1$$

solving for $~\ddot\varphi~$ and linearized

$$\ddot\varphi=\left(\omega^2-\frac gR\right)\,\varphi$$
which is correct

but if you first linearized the Hamiltonian  and then applying equation (1) you obtain this equation of motion

$$\ddot\varphi=\omega^2\varphi$$

---

the linearized Hamiltonian

$$H=\frac 12\,m{R}^{2}{\dot\varphi }^{2}-\frac 12\,m{R}^{2}{\omega}^{2}{\varphi }^{2}-m
R\,g
$$